# Query the entire hierarchy based on a parent/child value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, hierarchy

**Data**:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ([parent_id] INT, [child_id] INT) ;

INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT  1, 2
UNION
SELECT  1, 3
UNION
SELECT  2, 3
UNION
SELECT  3, 4

UNION
SELECT  5, 5

UNION
SELECT  6, 6
UNION
SELECT  6, 7

UNION
SELECT  28, 29
UNION
SELECT  28, 30
UNION
SELECT  31, 29
UNION
SELECT  31, 32
```

**Goal**: To query the entire tree of the root parent based on a value in that hierarchy.

**Scenarios**:

If I choose to query for <_id> = 4 (..or 1 ..or 2 ..or 3), the query should return the following.

```
parent_id   child_id
1           2
1           3
2           3
3           4
```

if I choose to query for <_id> = 5, the query should return the following.

```
parent_id   child_id
5           5
```

If I choose to query for <_id> = 7 (..or 6), the query should return the following.

```
parent_id   child_id
6           6
6           7
```

If I choose to query for <_id> = 28, the query should return the following.

```
parent_id   child_id
28          29
28          30
```

If I choose to query for <_id> = 29, the query should return the following.

```
parent_id   child_id
28          29
28          30
31          29
31          32
```

**My attempt**: Either doesn't return the ENTIRE hierarchy (@probe_id 4), returns dups (@probe_id = 2), or doesn't return all branches (@probe_id = 29), and etc.

```
DECLARE @probe_id INT = 4 ;
WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  [child_id]
              , [parent_id]
        FROM    @Data
        WHERE   [parent_id] = @probe_id
                OR [child_id] = @probe_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  [T].[child_id]
              , [T].[parent_id]
        FROM    @Data AS [T]
        JOIN    CTE AS [C]
        ON      [T].[parent_id] = [C].[child_id]
    )
SELECT      [parent_id]
          , [child_id]
FROM        CTE
ORDER BY    [parent_id], [child_id]
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 ) ;
```

Comment: So you need to "transverse" in *both* directions regardless of the ID? So for ID 4 you can  only go "down" the hierarchy, but for 2 you would go both up and down?

Comment: You have a table of arcs and you want all related arcs, **not nodes**.

Comment: @ThomA, yes. I want to "traverse" in both directions, regardless of the id. So when I query for 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, I want the entire tree. Same for 6 or 7. Same for 5 (only one level anyways). For for 28 or 30, the entire hierarchy. Same for 31 or 32. For 29, I want both branches since it's used in both branches.

Comment: @TheImpaler: hmm.. yea. all arcs (if I understand you correctly). And I wish we used postgreSQL. It has some cool bells and whistles.

Comment: The "bigger" problem, I suppose, is for when you pass a value of `2`; the row with the values `1` and `3` wouldn't show, as it's not part of the branch at the entry point. If you switched to a `hierarchyid` you would honestly have a much easier time.

Comment: @ThomA When I pass in probe_id = 2, I get the following back (which is buggy since it returns dups and doesn't return (1 3)).

(parent_id child_id)
(1 2),
(2 3),
(2 3),
(3 4),
(3 4)

Comment: If it's just that you are getting duplicate rows, why not just add a `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @ThomA: yea, I thought about it, but seems like a hack so leaving that as a last resort, but there's still an issue with (1 3) not being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want first detect the root and then traverse all the tree from the root. Try

```
declare @id  int = 6;

with h1 as (
   select [parent_id], [child_id], 0 level
   from dd --source table
   where @id in ([parent_id], [child_id])

   union all
  
   select dd.[parent_id], dd.[child_id], level +1
   from h1
   join dd on dd.[child_id] = h1.[parent_id]
      --  prevent short circuit looping 
      and h1.[child_id] <> h1.[parent_id]
), 
root as (
  select top(1) parent_id
  from h1
  order by level desc
),
h2 as (
   select dd.parent_id, dd.[child_id]
   from dd 
   join root on dd.parent_id = root.parent_id

   union all

   select dd.[parent_id], dd.[child_id]
   from h2
   join dd on dd.[parent_id] = h2.[child_id]
      and h2.[child_id] <> h2.[parent_id]
)
select distinct * 
from h2
```

**EDIT**

For multi-root hierarchy replace above `root` expression with

```
root as (
  select parent_id
  from h1 a
  where not exists (
     select 1 
     from h1 b 
     where a.parent_id = b.child_id 
           -- self-referencing root is ok
           and a.parent_id != b.parent_id )
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v03g2Ya0)

Comment: This is fantastic @Serg. I started approaching the problem with that intent as well but was unable to query the root-parent just right. Played around with your query and it returns results as expected for the most part except when id = 29. Since 29 has 2 different root parents (28 and 31), would it be possible to return both branches for such scenario?

Comment: @007, See the edited version

Comment: You da man! This is FANTASTIC. Thank you @Serg. Will take me a bit to understand all this, pretty neat.